# Нужна помощь с реализацией задачи на ассемблере( массив структур)

Tags: ассемблер, linked-list

Нужна помощь в выполнении задания. Код есть, но не работает (((

1)  Создать сегмент кодов (например, с именем Code1), в котором реализовать следующее
задачи: на базе массива структур А1 создать кольцевой двунаправленный список
для чего в поле left структуры А1 [0] записывается смещение в сегменте структуры
А1 [4], а в поле right структуры А1 [0] - смещение в сегменте структуры А1 [3]; в поле
left структуры А1 [3] записывается смещение в сегменте структуры А1 [0], а в поле right
структуры А1 [3] - смещение в сегменте структуры А1 [1], и т.д. в соответствии с порядком,
заданный в массиве Order. При создании программы для индексации массивов
структур использовать байт по адресу I_struc, а для доступа к элементам
массива Order - байт по адресу I_order.

2) Создать еще один логический сегмент данных (например, с именем Data2), в котором
задать директиву Db "Null", "One", "Two", Three ',' 'Four

3) Создать еще один логический сегмент кодов (например, с именем Code2), в котором с
помощью цепных команд переписать имена элементов списка в поля namex
структур, формирующих список. Обеспечить безусловную передачу управления из
сегмента Code1 в сегмент Code2 с помощью непрямой межсегментной передачи
управления.

Код того, что есть:

```
***.386
Node struc
namex db 5 dup (?)
left dw ?
right dw ?
Node ENDS
Data1 segment use16
I_struc db ?
I_order db ?
Order db 0,3,1,2,4
A1 Node 5 dup(<>)
adress dw begin2
Data1 ends
Data2 segment use16
Db 'Null', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four' 
Data2 ends
code1 segment use16
    assume cs:code1, es:Data1
begin:
mov ax, Data1
mov ds, ax
mov si, 0;
mov di, 0
mov bx, 0
lea bx, A1[0]
add bx, type A1
add bx, type A1
add bx, type A1
mov A1[di].right, bx
add bx, type A1
mov A1[di].left, bx
xor bx, bx
add di, type A1
lea bx, A1[0]
add bx, type A1
add bx, type A1
mov A1[di].right, bx
add bx, type A1
mov A1[di].left, bx
xor bx, bx
add di, type A1
lea bx, A1[0]
add bx, type A1
mov A1[di].left, bx
add bx, type A1
add bx, type A1
add bx, type A1
mov A1[di].right, bx
xor bx, bx
add di, type A1
lea bx, A1[0]
mov A1[di].left, bx
add bx, type A1
mov A1[di].right, bx
xor bx, bx
add di, type A1
lea bx, A1[0]
mov A1[di].right, bx
add bx, type A1
add bx, type A1
mov A1[di].left, bx
jmp dword ptr adress

end1:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
code1 ends
code2 segment use16
    assume cs:code2, es:Data1, ds:Data2
begin2:
mov ax, Data1
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, Data2
    mov ds, ax
    mov esi, 0
    mov eax, 9
    ;mov I1, 0
    mov si, 0
    mov bx, 0
    cld
    mov di, 0001h
    mov cx, 4
    lea si, A1[esi]
    rep movsb
    mov cx, 3
    inc di
    lea si, A1[eax]
    rep movsb
    mov cx, 3
    inc di
    add eax, type A1
    lea si, A1[eax]
    rep movsb
    mov cx, 5
    inc di
    add eax, type A1
    lea si, A1[eax]
    rep movsb
    mov cx, 4
    inc di
    add eax, type A1
    lea si, A1[eax]
    rep movsb





    jmp far ptr end1
    code2 ends
    end begin

    end begin2***
```